# Chnage after login page to dashboard to manage products in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, login, redirection

I want to change after login url in admin panel.
It is currently opening dashboard page.
How can I change it to another url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `System->configuration->admin->Startup Page` and for the field `Startup Page` select what ever you need

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> System->configuration->admin->Startup Page select  Manage Products
>   Under **Catalog** group